# redirecting is not working in ajax

Tags: ajax

**This below script is in view/template folder.**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#change").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "common/customer.php",
                data: { oldemail: $("#oldemail").val(), newemail: $("#newemail").val() }
            });
          });
        });
        </script>
```

> I want to send data in common/customer.php but it is not working. I
>   already used ../common/customer.php but same problem. What is the
>   solution?

Comment: there is nothing to redirect user anywhere... this is only for AJAX post.

Comment: what do you mean by `redirect`?

Comment: I mean that i want to send my data in another file which is in the common folder.

Answer (score 1):

Its a absolute path problem.
Your script is in view/template
If your path of javascript file is like something,

> view/template/myjavascript.js

And if your path of customer.php file is

> view/common/

Then you must switch your directory by `../`
Use

> ../common/customer.php

Its a relative path of your file.

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation, you must declare the data type:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

TRY...

```
url: "/common/customer.php", // note the leading slash
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry friends problem was in my html code. I used the type of input submit but when i changed it into button then it is working fine. Thanks to all of you.**